# How to enable Zabbix tomcat received bytes per second item?

Tags: java, monitoring, jmx, zabbix

I'm using Zabbix and I run a java application with some JMX arguments. When I added an item such as Tomcat received bytes, It was not supported. How can  I enable this item?

[image]

I tried to add **catalina-jmx-remote** dependency to the application.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina-jmx-remote</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

How can I enable tomcat monitoring on the Zabbix?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
jmx["Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name=\"http-8080\"",bytesReceived]
```

or

```
jmx["Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name=\"http-nio-8080\"",bytesReceived]
```

Comment: Where should I use this?

Comment: @NasibullohYandashev in Zabbix. instead your jmx["Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name=\"{$PROTOCOL_HANDLER_HTTP}\'",bytesReceived]. Maybe JMX connection is OK but problem with jmx-key in zabbix: remove quotes or http-nio-8080 instead http-8080.

Comment: I did as you said. When I did the first time, state of the item has changed to __Enabled__ after a few minutes It changed to __Not Supported__ state. Maybe must I do any changes on the application side?

Comment: Was my solution  correct? I mean dependency for maven

Comment: @NasibullohYandashev On your picture I see that GarbageCollector key works fine. That I think that JMX-connection is allright. And I think that you do not need maven-dependency. Are you tried with nio? Try jmx["Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name=\"http-nio-8080\"",bytesReceived]

Comment: I used both __jmx["Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name=\"http-nio-10080\"",bytesReceived] __ and __jmx["Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name=\"http-nio-8080\"",bytesReceived]__ but It is not working. I dont know what the problem. 10080 is port of tomcat in my case

Comment: @NasibullohYandashev If you are familiar with MissionControl then connect to tomcat (by IP and JMX-port). Go to the "MBean Browser" tab, and you will see the "folders". One of them is "Catalina". It will mean that everything is fine with JMX-connection. Go to the Catalina\GlobalRequestProcessor folder and you will see the key: "http-nio-xxxx" or "http-xxxx". This key you must insert in to zabbix jmx-string. Try this key with quotes or without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx Anatoly Samoylenko
i succese JMX monitoring for "spring boot"

[AS-IS]
jmx["Tomcat:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name=http-nio-80",bytesReceived]

[TO-BE]
jmx["Tomcat:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name=\"http-nio-80\"",bytesReceived]

very very impotant \"

good luck~

Comment: Maybe you could formulate your answer a little better? :)